# <c:out value="Test"/> inside jspx doesn't show in browser

Tags: jsp, maven, jstl, jspx

When I try to test my jstl lib (jstl-1.1.2.jar & standard-1.1.2.jar) by adding  it doesn't show anything in the browser.

this is my home.jspx:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jsp:root
    xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    version="2.1">

<jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8" />
<jsp:output omit-xml-declaration="true" />
<jsp:output doctype-root-element="HTML"
            doctype-system="about:legacy-compat" />

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>gdgdfgdg</title>

</head>
<body>
<h1>fsdf</h1>
<c:out value="Test"/>
</body>
</html>

</jsp:root>
```

Necessary jars are added. Can't figure out what's the problem.

EDITED:

This is the source code, the browser receives:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML SYSTEM "about:legacy-compat">
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="content-type"/>
    <title>gdgdfgdg</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>fsdf</h1>
    <c:out value="TEST"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

I added the following dependencies to maven and it loaded the right jars as described at the top properly..

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: You need to be more specific. How exactly did you install JSTL? What exactly is the generated HTML output? You mean, when you open the page in browser and do rightclick and *View Source*, then you see the `<c:out>` still raw and unparsed in there? So far it looks just like that you didn't install JSTL properly at all. Hover the `[jstl]` tag below the question and click the *info* link for instructions.

Comment: just edited my question.. sorry and thanks

Comment: No, no, the JSTL tag is not been parsed correctly at all! You should not be seeing any JSP tag library artifacts in generated HTML output. They are supposed to be parsed and executed by the server and generate HTML output (the webbrowser doesn't understand JSP at all, it only understands HTML). You should be seeing just `TEST` in the generated HTML output instead of `<c:out value="TEST"/>`. Well, coming back to the cause: you turn out to be using Maven. Sorry, this is beyond me. I've at least added the `[maven]` tag so that you get the right attention. Good luck.

Comment: But the whole tag is not interpreted as text? How can this happen? Thanks for your help..

Comment: I have no idea what exactly you mean with that, so I'll just ignore that part. Fact is, JSTL tags are not been parsed. The probable causes are is that JSTL isn't declared or installed. It is properly declared, so it's likely not installed. In other words, JSTL is not present in webapp's runtime classpath. In your case, Maven is responsible for that part. So something's clearly wrong in Maven configuration. Perhaps you used completely wrong coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

The provided jspx works fine in my environment, Tomcat 6.0 and with the following:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl-impl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
    <artifactId>el-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

According to [Apache](http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/doc/standard-doc/intro.html), 1.1.2 taglibs should work on Tomcat 5.0 or later, but since you included the JSP version 2.1 in the head of the jspx, you need to run on a Servlet spec 2.5 or later server, such as Tomcat 6.

Your best bet is to use the dependencies i've provided and make sure your servlet container is recent.

Answer (score -2):

Try this simple .jsp page if anything works at all. Test page uses random fmt and c features.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %><%@ 
    taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %><%@
    page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"
    import="java.util.*,
    java.text.*
    "
%><%

String var0 = "Foodoo0 " + System.currentTimeMillis();
pageContext.setAttribute("var1", "Foodoo1 " + System.currentTimeMillis());
pageContext.setAttribute("var2", "Foodoo2 " + System.currentTimeMillis());

double distance = 1234.567;
pageContext.setAttribute("distance", distance);

%><!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <title>Test page</title>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>

var0=<%= var0 %> <br/>
var1=${var1} <br/>
<c:out value="COut Foo" /> <br/>
var2=<c:out value="${var2}" /> <br/>

<br/>
Use locale fi_FI<br/>
<fmt:setLocale value="fi_FI" scope="page" />
<c:set var="distanceEL" value="${distance}" />
fmt0=${distance} | ${distanceEL} <br/>
fmt1=<fmt:formatNumber pattern="0.0" value="${distance}" /> <br/>
fmt2=<fmt:formatNumber pattern="0.00" value="${distanceEL}" /> <br/>
fmt3=<%= new DecimalFormat("0.0").format(distance) %>

<br/>
Use locale en_US<br/>
<fmt:setLocale value="en_US" scope="page" />
<c:set var="distanceEL" value="${distance+3456.78}" />
fmt0=${distance} | ${distanceEL} <br/>
fmt1=<fmt:formatNumber pattern="0.0" value="${distance}" /> <br/>
fmt2=<fmt:formatNumber pattern="0.00" value="${distanceEL}" /> <br/>
fmt3=<%= new DecimalFormat("0.0").format(distance) %>

</body>
</html>
```

I have used these libraries in Tomcat6 server, but they are a bit old. Have not bothered to update cause Tomcat6 itself is a legacy anyway.

- lib/jstl-api-1.2.jar
- lib/jstl-impl-1.2.jar
- lib/el-api.jar_OLD   (renamed old tomcat .jar to disable it)
- lib/el-api-1.1.jar
- lib/el-impl-1.1.jar

These are the files I use in Tomcat7 server,  Tomcat7 has lib/el-api.jar and lib/jasper-el.jar which are fine. No need to update them.

- javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api-1.2.1.jar
- javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-1.2.2.jar

Download fresh jars from http://search.maven.org/#browse|707331597 and http://search.maven.org/#browse|-1308691387 links.

Make sure use proper webapp specs version attribute in mywebapp/WEB-INF/web.xml file.
This is Tomcat6 webapp.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" 
   xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
>
  <description>My webapp</description>
  <display-name>My webapp</display-name>
</web-app>
```

This it Tomcat7 webapp.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
  version="3.0" 
>
  <description>My webapp</description>
  <display-name>My webapp</display-name>
</web-app>
```

Comment: OP is using JSPX and Maven. This answer is completely replacing them altogether with JSP and "fiddling with loose JAR files". This isn't making any sense.

Comment: BalusC, Let OP decide this is to pinpoint problem one by one, Maven config, manual dropin .jar or jsp/jspx file is not the point here I guess anyway. They are close enough when it comes to JSTL problem solving. thx.

Comment: Dude, this is like telling a Java developer to try C# because something didn't work in Java due to a configuration problem. Why not just fix the configuration problem by its roots instead?